# Unsupported media type was attempted to be imported as a module

Tags: deno

I used denodb Lib from this link "https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.0.23/mod.ts" then I got the below Error:

```
error: Import 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denjucks/dex/master/mod.ts' failed: 404 Not Found
    at https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.0.23/deps.ts:3:0
```

That because the DEX library moved from this link "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denjucks/dex/master/mod.ts".

So I tried this solution [link](https://github.com/eveningkid/denodb/pull/210) (they forked denodb and changed the dex url in deps.ts ).

After that I got the below Error:

```
error: An unsupported media type was attempted to be imported as a module.
  Specifier: https://github.com/takxlz/denodb/blob/master/mod.ts
  MediaType: Unknown
```

Any idea how to solve this Error? (Also I tried clean cache but still same error happen)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/takxlz/denodb/blob/master/mod.ts is actually a GitHub page (HTML page- `text/html`). The Deno modules which are imported are either `text/plain` or `application/typescript`. So use the raw version of the file uploaded on GitHub-

```js
import * as Denodb from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takxlz/denodb/master/mod.ts";
```

```sh
curl -I "https://github.com/takxlz/denodb/blob/master/mod.ts"
# - content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

curl -I "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takxlz/denodb/master/mod.ts"
# - content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

curl -I "https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.0.23/mod.ts"
# - content-type: application/typescript; charset=utf-8
```