# Is it possible to import a module in deno from a github release?

Tags: javascript, github, deno

I would like to import a module from github in deno, which is only available as github release and is not part of the code in the repository.

I would like to import: `https://github.com/zingi/random-lon-lat-generator/releases/download/v0.1.0/random_lon_lat_generator.js`

I tried:

```js
import * as wasm from 'https://github.com/zingi/random-lon-lat-generator/releases/download/v0.1.0/random_lon_lat_generator.js'
```

which gives this error:

```
Download https://github.com/zingi/random-lon-lat-generator/releases/download/v0.1.0/random_lon_lat_generator.js
Download https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/352299341/6ca4b280-9638-11eb-9f4a-c7b6b890c5e9?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210405%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210405T161838Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=82fbc720c3a05232836678385da43cecd2a9d29ca959f736e5e8a47ce62b23bf&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=352299341&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Drandom_lon_lat_generator.js&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
error: An unsupported media type was attempted to be imported as a module.
  Specifier: https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/352299341/6ca4b280-9638-11eb-9f4a-c7b6b890c5e9?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210405%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210405T161838Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=82fbc720c3a05232836678385da43cecd2a9d29ca959f736e5e8a47ce62b23bf&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=352299341&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Drandom_lon_lat_generator.js&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
  MediaType: Unknown
```

I know I could easily import a module if it was part of the tracked files in git using `raw.githubusercontent.com`

But because the module also contains compiled WebAssembly, I don't want to track it with git.

If it is not possible, do you have any other suggestions on how to make this work?

---

**Edit**: The error message seems to be the same as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66735453/unsupported-media-type-was-attempted-to-be-imported-as-a-module). But the problem source is different and can not be solved with the accepted answer from there. The assets in github releases seem to not have a permanent link, like the tracked files in git with `raw.githubusercontent.com`. The links to files provided on a github release page seem to forward (`302`) to a generated, available for a limited time url like: `github-releases.githubusercontent.com/...`. So it would be interesting to know, if there is any possiblity to get a permanent "raw" link to a github asset.

Comment: Its it because, its `application/xml` not JavaScript , also note that `MediaType: Unknown` When, I request it it gave me http 403 error.

Comment: Requested from `server: AmazonS3` , Error : `<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<X-Amz-Expires>300</X-Amz-Expires>
<Expires>2021-04-05T16:23:38Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2021-04-05T21:03:05Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>CJBY8NSXG35XJHJD</RequestId>
<HostId>XT38SvXhRD6ZKG7Vx0tt1GikPA6AyVaqeCQFS4aUpqYZbIEf0k3ZbmO0wzh2Q4RB5E9Gemwpy+g=</HostId>
</Error>`

Comment: @Nur You probably tried to download from the redirected url, which seems to be a automatically generated url, only available for a limited time. If you use the `https://github.com/zingi/random-lon-lat-generator/releases/download/v0.1.0/random_lon_lat_generator.js` you should not get a 403 error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsupported media type was attempted to be imported as a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66735453/unsupported-media-type-was-attempted-to-be-imported-as-a-module)

Comment: @ShivamSingla No, it does not directly answer my question. I already stated in the problem description, that the module code is not in the git code, and hence not available over `raw.githubusercontent.com`. I guess there are no raw permanent links to assets in github releases?

Comment: @zingi seems there is no other way to get content-type as `text/plain` or `application/javascript` from GitHub for the release assets. But there is a workaround, you could create a little server on [Glitch](https://glitch.com/) which downloads the asset and responses back with the correct/desired content-type.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub release download URL actually redirects to an S3 pre-signed URL that *itself* sends back a response with the `application/octet-stream` Content-Type header *no matter what the content is*. Since deno doesn't know that content type, that's why you see that error message.

You can however import directly from the git tag that corresponds to the release via the `raw.githubusercontent.com` CDN. For example, you could import from the std lib with:

```js
import { serve } from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/deno_std/0.92.0/http/server.ts";
```

If it's a built artifact that can't be accessed through GitHub's raw usercontent CDN, you can push to an external data store like GCS or S3. They both can be exposed via a URL and you can then import from there.

Some module registries also allow you to have a build step, for example [nest.land](https://nest.land) gives that option. You can then hook that into the same CI workflow as the release workflow.

---

For your specific case though, I can see from the repo that you're building a wasm module; you can also include a TypeScript or JavaScript file that serves as an entrypoint for your wasm module. This is how it's done in the standard lib's [hash module](https://deno.land/std@0.95.0/hash) for example.

Comment: You can also download individual files from GitHub Releases. See my referenced repo: one file: `https://github.com/zingi/random-lon-lat-generator/releases/download/v0.1.0/random_lon_lat_generator.js`

Comment: Both one file and zip file seem to 302. However the zip url seems to redirect to a more permanent url: 

`https://github.com/zingi/random-lon-lat-generator/archive/refs/tags/v0.1.0.zip` => 

`https://codeload.github.com/zingi/random-lon-lat-generator/zip/refs/tags/v0.1.0`

Comment: About the `raw.githubusercontent.com`: I already mentioned 3 times, that the module code is _not_ (yet) part of the git code and hence not available like that.

Comment: I just checked, and the zip archive related to a release seems to only include a snapshot of the git tracked code at that time. So it doesn't contain the module code, which is only available in the release assets.

Comment: @zingi yeah I reformulated the first pragraph to be clearer and also included a couple of options that might help you out